# How to run jar packages uploaded by oneself on an HDFS cluster

Tags: java, hdfs

I have a custom jar package that I want to place in the directory folder of hdfs. I want to try running this jar package, and the command I use is:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar hdfs://10.150.20.80:8020/data/resource/jar/udf/hive-udf-1.2.0.jar com.payegis.bigdata.live.utils.HbaseSwapPairDelete --node cdh01,cdh02,cdh03 --env prod
```

The error message is as follows:

```
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.
JAR does not exist or is not a normal file:
file:/tmp/hsperfdata_Hdfs/hdfs:/10.150.20.80:8020/data/resource/jar/udf/live-udf-1.2.0.jar
```

I also tried to leave the path of hdfs://in the field before the command, but the error message is as follows:

```
JAR does not exist or is not a normal file:/data/resource/jar/udf/live udf 1.2.0.jar
```

I can execute this command from the local path, but I cannot switch to the path on hdfs.

What should I do to run the JAR package?